# How to apply multiple Filters on an Adapter Or Listview?

Tags: android, listview, adaptor, listview-filter

I have ListView with list of Bus information, I want to apply the multiple filter on Adapter or in ListView, I have already done the live search filter on ListView,

Here is my Activity:

```
public class FilterListActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

    private static List<Country> countries = Storage.getItems();
    private EditText editTextFilter;
    private ListView listViewCountries;
    private CountryListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adapter = new CountryListAdapter(this, countries);

        editTextFilter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextFilter);
        editTextFilter.addTextChangedListener(this);

        listViewCountries = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewCountries);
        listViewCountries.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

}
```

and below is my screen view
[image]

When i search on text view its searches very well but i want to filter ListView with area and population also.

Comment: you need do more research ... try something, write some code ... and then eventually back here if you would have problems with your code ... as now your question is: **write the app like xxx for me for free**

Comment: Sorry Selvin, I was asked question in wrong way, this approach i have followed this working fine for country search, but i want to implement same functionality for Area Filter as well as Population Filter

Answer (score 0):

Apply Multiple Filter in Listview and also use the multi sorting in ListView, try this link:

https://github.com/apurv3039/filter_listview/tree/master

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add condition in performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) method like below

```
ListAdapter implements Filterable{
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            List<DrugsListPojo> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mdataListFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ((mdataListFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    filterList.add(mdataListFilterList.get(i));
                }else  if ((mdataListFilterList.get(i).getDrugTypeName().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    filterList.add(mdataListFilterList.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mdataListFilterList.size();
            results.values = mdataListFilterList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        dataList = (List<DrugsListPojo>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   etSearchbox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearchbox);
    etSearchbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           // Dar_List.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            List<DarParClass> Dar_List_New= new ArrayList();
            for (DarParClass var : Dar_List)
            {
                if (var.Date1.contains(arg0)){//you can add multiple Filters here with '||'
                    Dar_List_New.add(var);
                }
            }
            adapter = new Dar_List_ListViewAdapter(Dar_List_New, getBaseContext());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And:

```
public class DarParClass {
  String KodD,Kodmh,Ham,Rate,RateM,Price1,Distin1,Pricesum1,Date1,Refe1_n;

  public DarParClass(String KodD, String Kodmh, String Ham, String Rate, String RateM, String Price1, String Distin1, String Pricesum1, String Date1, String Refe1_n) {
    this.KodD = KodD;

    this.Kodmh = Kodmh;
    this.Ham = Ham;
    this.Rate = Rate;
    this.RateM = RateM;
    this.Price1 = Price1;
    this.Distin1 = Distin1;
    this.Pricesum1 = Pricesum1;
    this.Date1 = Date1;
    this.Refe1_n = Refe1_n;
  }
  public String getKodD() {return KodD;}

  public String getKodmh() {return Kodmh;}
  public String getHam() {return Ham;}
  public String getRate() {return Rate;}
  public String getRateM() {return RateM;}
  public String getPrice1() {return Price1;}
  public String getDistin1() {return Distin1;}
  public String getPricesum1() {return Pricesum1;}
  public String getDate1() {return Date1;}
  public String getRefe1_n() {return Refe1_n;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful when responding to questions with other answers, as it can help readers understand the key differences in your approach. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?